# Jquery Mobile Dialog on page load, the dialog doesn't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I'm trying to get jQuery dialog to appear after webpage loads so that the user can input some important data so that the homepage can load some data.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.mobile.changePage( "CrewPopupDialog.html", { role: "dialog" } );
            });
```

When the page is loaded nothing happens. I am using the exact syntax from the jQuery Mobile API page http://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/ The dialog page is a separate html file but I didn't think that would cause an issue.

Google Chrome console is returning this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'changePage' of undefined

Comment: Have you included jquery mobile library? If yes, is it under (and not above) jquery library?

Comment: It's under another jquery library. Should I move it up?

Comment: I think I fixed it I was including the jQuery 1.10.0 library. I commented that out and moved the jQuery 1.9.1 library to the top. It seems to be working now thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you imports are in the right order. jQuery then UI and lastly jQuery Mobile. My dialog now loads correctly and with the proper formatting.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```